# Two identical files have different file size based on the way it is written from C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, file-io, encoding

I am trying to write to a file an array of object serialised into JSON format.  I am trying to write it in two different way as shown below.

```
ToSerialise[] Obj = new ToSerialise[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Obj[i] = new ToSerialise();
        }

        //First form of serialising
        UnicodeEncoding uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        String SerialisedOutput;
        SerialisedOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Obj, Formatting.Indented);
        FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@"C:\file1.log", FileMode.CreateNew);
        fs1.Write(uniEncoding.GetBytes(SerialisedOutput), 0, uniEncoding.GetByteCount(SerialisedOutput));
        fs1.Close();

        //Second form of serialising
        FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(@"C:\file2.log", FileMode.CreateNew);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs2);
        JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
        JsonSerializer js = new JsonSerializer();
        jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        js.Serialize(jw, Obj);
        jw.Close();
        fs2.Close();
```

Even though the content of both the files are same, they have different file size. Actually the first file is exactly twice the size of the second file. I tried comparing the output using textpad and it says they are excatly the same. Why do they have different file size?

I am running this on Windows 7 32 bit, .Net4

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried opening up the two files produced in WinHex or something similar? That would let you identify the differences between them in the raw hex and might help you find out what's causing them to be saved with different file sizes.

Comment: "Two identical files have different file size". This is just a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @EJP Right, that's true, but some file comparison utilities are showing the files identical. I'm having the same problem now. The question is how (and, in my case, the second file is about 200% size!).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Even though the content of both the files are same, they have different file size.

If they have a different size, then they *definitely* have different contents. A file is (pretty much) just a sequence of bytes - and if two sequences have different lengths, they're different sequences.

In this case, the two files both represent the same *text*, but using different encodings - `file2` will use UTF-8, and `file1` will use UTF-16.

To think of it a different way: if you saved the same picture to two files, one as JPEG and one as PNG, would you expect the files to be the same size?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Now I see the file properties, it says ANSI and Unicode respectively.

Comment: @Manoj: "ANSI" is just a guess here (and it's not even a precise term in this context). It's *really* using UTF-8 - but if your text only contains ASCII, then you can read it with any ASCII-compatible encoding and you'll get the same results.

Comment: I am a bit confused now. UTF-8 means it uses 8 bits to represent every character? I thought ASCII had 256 chars and so they match. UTF-16 would allow 65536 char variations and thus the space to represent more scripts. Is this right? But now I see wikipedia I see Unicode can be represented in UTF 8 and UTF 16. How is that?